# Registering in android using retrofit getting error Internal Server Error

Tags: android, api, gson, retrofit2

Hello any one can help me how to solve this error 
     Internal Server Error

In Postman its works fine and data saved successfully
but in android side its shows error

Please help me 
Thank you

```
API URL = https://www.glamorousshe.com/index.php?route=customapi/customer/register

Method : POST
        Request Parameters :
        {
            "firstname":"Tomas",                                //Mandatory
            "lastname" :"Jindal",                               //Mandatory
            "email":"tomas@onjection.com",                      //Mandatory
            "telephone":"9999722105",                           //Mandatory
            "password":"123456",                                //Mandatory
            "confirm":"123456"                                  //Mandatory
        }

        Response : 
            {
              "data": {
                "customer": {
                  "customer_id": "3",
                  "customer_group_id": "1",
                  "store_id": "0",
                  "language_id": "1",
                  "firstname": "Tomas",
                  "lastname": "Jindal",
                  "email": "tomasjindal07@onjection.com",
                  "telephone": "9999722105",
                  "fax": "",
                  "password": "65a88c9723bff009c430558dd382ca3960e4b27a",
                  "salt": "J4HtzYKO6",
                  "cart": null,
                  "wishlist": null,
                  "newsletter": "0",
                  "address_id": "8",
                  "custom_field": "",
                  "ip": "::1",
                  "status": "1",
                  "approved": "1",
                  "safe": "0",
                  "token": "",
                  "code": "",
                  "date_added": "2016-11-12 16:05:36"
                }
              },
              "status": 200
            }
```

/****** **Android Code** ******/
        /****** **API INTERFACE CLASS**  ******/

```
        public interface Api {

            @Headers({
                    "Accept: application/json",
                    "Content-type: application/json"
            })
            @FormUrlEncoded
            @POST("index.php?route=customapi/customer/register")
            Call<DefaultResponse> createUser(
                    @Field("firstname") String firstname,
                    @Field("lastname") String lastname,
                    @Field("telephone") String telephone,
                    @Field("email") String email,
                    @Field("password") String password,
                    @Field("confirm") String confirm

            );
        }
```

/**** **Retrofit Class** ****/

```
    public class RetrofitClient {

        private static final String AUTH = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(("glamorousshe07032018:9426473664").getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

        private static final String BASE_URL = "https://www.glamorousshe.com/";
        private static RetrofitClient mInstance;
        private Retrofit retrofit;


        private RetrofitClient() {
            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(
                            new Interceptor() {
                                @Override
                                public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                                    Request original = chain.request();

                                    Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                                            .addHeader("Authorization", AUTH)
                                            .method(original.method(), original.body());

                                    Request request = requestBuilder.build();
                                    return chain.proceed(request);
                                }
                            }
                    ).build();

            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .build();
        }

        public static synchronized RetrofitClient getInstance() {
            if (mInstance == null) {
                mInstance = new RetrofitClient();
            }
            return mInstance;
        }

        public Api getApi() {
            return retrofit.create(Api.class);
        }
    }
```

/**** **Register Activity Class**  *****/

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private EditText editTextEmail, editTextPassword, editTextFirstname, editTextTelephone,editTextConfirmPassword,editTextLastname;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editTextEmail = findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        editTextPassword = findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        editTextFirstname = findViewById(R.id.editTextFirstName);
        editTextLastname = findViewById(R.id.editTextLastName);
        editTextConfirmPassword= findViewById(R.id.editTextConfirmPassword);
        editTextTelephone = findViewById(R.id.editTexttelephone);


        findViewById(R.id.buttonSignUp).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.textViewLogin).setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

    }

    private void userSignUp() {
        String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
        String firstname = editTextFirstname.getText().toString().trim();
        String lastname = editTextLastname.getText().toString().trim();
        String telephone = editTextTelephone.getText().toString().trim();
        String confirm = editTextConfirmPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        if (email.isEmpty()) {
            editTextEmail.setError("Email is required");
            editTextEmail.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
            editTextEmail.setError("Enter a valid email");
            editTextEmail.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (password.isEmpty()) {
            editTextPassword.setError("Password required");
            editTextPassword.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if (confirm.isEmpty()) {
            editTextConfirmPassword.setError("Password required");
            editTextConfirmPassword.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (password.length() < 6) {
            editTextPassword.setError("Password should be atleast 6 character long");
            editTextPassword.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (firstname.isEmpty()) {
            editTextFirstname.setError("Name required");
            editTextFirstname.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if (lastname.isEmpty()) {
            editTextLastname.setError("Name required");
            editTextLastname.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (telephone.isEmpty()) {
            editTextTelephone.setError("School required");
            editTextTelephone.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        Call<DefaultResponse> call = RetrofitClient
                .getInstance()
                .getApi()
                .createUser(email, password, firstname, lastname, telephone, confirm);


        call.enqueue(new Callback<DefaultResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<DefaultResponse> call, Response<DefaultResponse> response) {
                if (response.code() == 200) {

                    DefaultResponse dr = response.body();
                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, dr.getMsg(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e("mess",response.message()+"");

               } else if (response.code() == 200) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User already exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e("mess2",response.message()+"");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<DefaultResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("mes2s",t.getMessage()+"");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttonSignUp:
                userSignUp();
                break;
            case R.id.textViewLogin:

                startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

/****** DEFAULT RESPONSE CLASS *******/

public class DefaultResponse {

```
@SerializedName("error")
private boolean err;

@SerializedName("message")
private String msg;

public DefaultResponse(boolean err, String msg) {
    this.err = err;
    this.msg = msg;
}

public boolean isErr() {
    return err;
}

public String getMsg() {
    return msg;
}
```

}

/******* Customer Api Php File *****/

```
<?php
class ControllerCustomapiCustomer extends Controller {

    private $error = ''; 

    public function register(){ 
        $method = $this->apirequest->getMethodFromRequestHeaders();

        if($method != 'POST'){
            $response['data'] = 'Method not Allowed';
            $response['status'] = 405;
            $this->apiresponse->send($response);
        }

        $this->load->model('account/customer');

        $this->load->language('account/register');

        $request_data = $this->apirequest->getDataFromRequestBody();
        //echo "fff";die;
//echo "<pre>";print_r($request_data);die;
        if($this->validate($request_data,true)){
            $customer_id = $this->model_account_customer->addCustomer($request_data);
            // Clear any previous login attempts for unregistered accounts.
            $this->model_account_customer->deleteLoginAttempts($request_data['email']);

            if ($this->config->get('config_customer_activity')) {
                $this->load->model('account/activity');

                $activity_data = array(
                    'customer_id' => $customer_id,
                    'name'        => $request_data['firstname'] . ' ' . $request_data['lastname']
                );

                $this->model_account_activity->addActivity('register', $activity_data);
            }

            $customer_info = $this->model_account_customer->getCustomer($customer_id);

            $response['data']['customer'] = $customer_info;
            $response['status'] = 200;
            $this->apiresponse->send($response);

        }else{
            $response['data']['warning'] = $this->error;
            $response['status'] = 200;
            $this->apiresponse->send($response);
        }
    }

    public function login(){
        $method = $this->apirequest->getMethodFromRequestHeaders();

        if($method != 'POST'){
            $response['data'] = 'Method not Allowed';
            $response['status'] = 405;
            $this->apiresponse->send($response);
        }

        $request_data = $this->apirequest->getDataFromRequestBody();

        $email = isset($request_data['email']) ? addslashes($request_data['email']) : '';
        $password = isset($request_data['password']) ? addslashes($request_data['password']) : '';

        if(!$email || !$password){
            $response['data'] = $this->language->get('error_login');;
            $response['status'] = 200;
            $this->apiresponse->send($response);
        }

        $this->load->model('account/customer');
        $this->load->language('account/login');

        $login_info = $this->model_account_customer->getLoginAttempts($email);

        if ($login_info && ($login_info['total'] >= $this->config->get('config_login_attempts')) && strtotime('-1 hour') < strtotime($login_info['date_modified'])) {
            $this->error = $this->language->get('error_attempts');
        }

        // Check if customer has been approved.
        $customer_info = $this->model_account_customer->getCustomerByEmail($email);

        /* if ($customer_info && !$customer_info['approved']) {
            $this->error = $this->language->get('error_approved');
        } */

        if (!$this->error) {
            if (!$this->customer->login($email, $password)) {
                $this->error = $this->language->get('error_login');

                $this->model_account_customer->addLoginAttempt($email);
            } else { 
                $this->model_account_customer->deleteLoginAttempts($email);
            }
        }

        if(!$this->error){
            $response['data']['customer'] = $customer_info;
            $response['status'] = 200;
            $this->apiresponse->send($response);
        }else{
            $response['data'] = $this->error;
            $response['status'] = 200;
            $this->apiresponse->send($response);
        }
    }

    public function getOrders(){
        $method = $this->apirequest->getMethodFromRequestHeaders();

        if($method != 'GET'){
            $response['data'] = 'Method not Allowed';
            $response['status'] = 405;
            $this->apiresponse->send($response);
        }

        $request_data = $this->apirequest->getDataFromRequestBody();

        $customer_id = isset($request_data['customer_id']) ? (int)$request_data['customer_id'] : 0;

        if(!$customer_id){
            $response['data'] = 'No Data Found';
            $response['status'] = 204;
            $this->apiresponse->send($response);
        }

        $page = isset($request_data['page']) ? (int)$request_data['page'] : 1;
        $limit = isset($request_data['limit']) ? (int)$request_data['limit'] : 20;
        $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;

        $this->load->model('customapi/customer');

        $orders = $this->model_customapi_customer->getOrders($customer_id,$start,$limit);
        $total_orders = $this->model_customapi_customer->getTotalOrders($customer_id);

        if($orders){
            $response['data']['orders'] = $orders;
            $response['data']['total_orders'] = $total_orders;
            $response['status'] = 200;
            $this->apiresponse->send($response);
        }else{
            $response['data'] = 'No Data Found';
            $response['status'] = 204;
            $this->apiresponse->send($response);
        }
    }

    public function getOrder(){
        $method = $this->apirequest->getMethodFromRequestHeaders();

        if($method != 'GET'){
            $response['data'] = 'Method not Allowed';
            $response['status'] = 405;
            $this->apiresponse->send($response);
        }

        $request_data = $this->apirequest->getDataFromRequestBody();

        $order_id = isset($request_data['order_id']) ? (int)$request_data['order_id'] : 0;

        if(!$order_id){
            $response['data'] = 'No Data Found';
            $response['status'] = 204;
            $this->apiresponse->send($response);
        }

        $this->load->model('customapi/customer');
        $order = $this->model_customapi_customer->getOrder($order_id);

        if($order){
            $response['data']['order'] = $order;
            $response['status'] = 200;
            $this->apiresponse->send($response);
        }else{
            $response['data'] = 'No Data Found';
            $response['status'] = 204;
            $this->apiresponse->send($response);
        }
    }

    public function getCustomFields(){
        $method = $this->apirequest->getMethodFromRequestHeaders();

        if($method != 'GET'){
            $response['data'] = 'Method not Allowed';
            $response['status'] = 405;
            $this->apiresponse->send($response);
        }

        $this->load->model('account/custom_field');
        $custom_fields = $this->model_account_custom_field->getCustomFields();

        if($custom_fields){
            $response['data'] = $custom_fields;
            $response['status'] = 200;
            $this->apiresponse->send($response);
        }else{
            $response['data'] = 'No Data Found';
            $response['status'] = 204;
            $this->apiresponse->send($response);
        }
    }

    public function getAddresses(){ 
        $method = $this->apirequest->getMethodFromRequestHeaders();

        if($method != 'GET'){
            $response['data'] = 'Method not Allowed';
            $response['status'] = 405;
            $this->apiresponse->send($response);
        }

        $request_data = $this->apirequest->getDataFromRequestBody();

        $customer_id = isset($request_data['customer_id']) ? (int)$request_data['customer_id'] : 0;

        if(!$customer_id){
            $response['data'] = 'No Data Found';
            $response['status'] = 204;
            $this->apiresponse->send($response);
        }

        $this->load->model('customapi/customer');

        $addresses = $this->model_customapi_customer->getAddresses($customer_id);

        if($addresses){ 
            $response['data']['address'] = $addresses;
            $response['status'] = 200;
            $this->apiresponse->send($response);
        }else{ 
            $response['data'] = 'No Data Found';
            $response['status'] = 204;
            $this->apiresponse->send($response);
        }
    }

    public function updateAddress(){ 
        $method = $this->apirequest->getMethodFromRequestHeaders();

        if($method != 'POST'){
            $response['data'] = 'Method not Allowed';
            $response['status'] = 405;
            $this->apiresponse->send($response);
        }

        $request_data = $this->apirequest->getDataFromRequestBody();

        $customer_id = isset($request_data['customer_id']) ? (int)$request_data['customer_id'] : 0;
        $address_id = isset($request_data['address_id']) ? (int)$request_data['address_id'] : 0;

        if(!$customer_id){
            $response['data'] = 'Bad Request';
            $response['status'] = 400;
            $this->apiresponse->send($response);
        }

        $validate = $this->validate($request_data,false,array('address'));
        if($validate){ 

            $this->load->model('customapi/customer');

            if($address_id){ 
                $address_id = $this->model_customapi_customer->editAddress($customer_id,$address_id,$request_data);
            }else{ 
                $address_id = $this->model_customapi_customer->addAddress($customer_id,$request_data);
            }

            $response['data'] = 'Data has been successfully saved.';
            $response['status'] = 200;
            $this->apiresponse->send($response);
        }else{ 
            $response['data']['warning'] = $this->error;
            $response['status'] = 200;
            $this->apiresponse->send($response);
        }
    }

    public function deleteAddress(){
        $method = $this->apirequest->getMethodFromRequestHeaders();

        if($method != 'DELETE'){
            $response['data'] = 'Method not Allowed';
            $response['status'] = 405;
            $this->apiresponse->send($response);
        }

        $request_data = $this->apirequest->getDataFromRequestBody();

        $customer_id = isset($request_data['customer_id']) ? (int)$request_data['customer_id'] : 0;
        $address_id = isset($request_data['address_id']) ? (int)$request_data['address_id'] : 0;

        if(!$customer_id || !$address_id){
            $response['data'] = 'Bad Request';
            $response['status'] = 400;
            $this->apiresponse->send($response);
        }

        $this->load->model('customapi/customer');
        $this->load->language('account/address');

        $total = $this->model_customapi_customer->getTotalAddresses($customer_id);

        if($total <= 1){
            $response['data'] = $this->language->get('error_delete');
            $response['status'] = 200;
            $this->apiresponse->send($response);
        }

        $this->model_customapi_customer->deleteAddress($customer_id,$address_id);

        $response['data'] = 'Address successfully deleted';
        $response['status'] = 200;
        $this->apiresponse->send($response);
    }

    public function registerApp(){
        $method = $this->apirequest->getMethodFromRequestHeaders();

        if($method != 'POST'){
            $response['data'] = 'Method not Allowed';
            $response['status'] = 405;
            $this->apiresponse->send($response);
        }

        $request_data = $this->apirequest->getDataFromRequestBody();

        $data['customer_id']        = $user_id          = isset($request_data['customer_id']) ? (int)$request_data['customer_id'] : 0;
        $data['email']              = $email            = isset($request_data['email']) ? addslashes($request_data['email']) : '';
        $data['type']               = $type             = (isset($request_data['type']) && in_array($request_data['type'], array('A','I'))) ? $request_data['type'] : 'A';
        $data['registration_id']    = $registration_id  = isset($request_data['registration_id']) ? addslashes($request_data['registration_id']) : '';

        if(!$registration_id){
            $response['data'] = 'Invalid Request';
            $response['status'] = 405;
            $this->apiresponse->send($response);
        }

        $this->load->model('customapi/customer');
        $this->model_customapi_customer->addAppUser($data);

        $response['data'] = 'Data has been saved successfully.';
        $response['status'] = 200;
        $this->apiresponse->send($response);
    }

    protected function validate($request_data = array(),$password_check = false,$location = array('address','account')){

        if(empty($request_data)){
            return true;
        }

        if ((utf8_strlen(trim($request_data['firstname'])) < 1) || (utf8_strlen(trim($request_data['firstname'])) > 32)) {
            $this->error['firstname'] = $this->language->get('error_firstname');
        }

        if ((utf8_strlen(trim($request_data['lastname'])) < 1) || (utf8_strlen(trim($request_data['lastname'])) > 32)) {
            $this->error['lastname'] = $this->language->get('error_lastname');
        }

        if($password_check){
            if ((utf8_strlen($request_data['email']) > 96) || !filter_var($request_data['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $this->error['email'] = $this->language->get('error_email');
            }

             if ($this->model_account_customer->getTotalCustomersByEmail($request_data['email'])) {
                $this->error['account'] = $this->language->get('error_exists');
            } 

            if ((utf8_strlen($request_data['telephone']) < 3) || (utf8_strlen($request_data['telephone']) > 32)) {
                $this->error['telephone'] = $this->language->get('error_telephone');
            }
        }

        if ((utf8_strlen(trim($request_data['address_1'])) < 3) || (utf8_strlen(trim($request_data['address_1'])) > 128)) {
            $this->error['address_1'] = $this->language->get('error_address_1');
        }

        if ((utf8_strlen(trim($request_data['city'])) < 2) || (utf8_strlen(trim($request_data['city'])) > 128)) {
            $this->error['city'] = $this->language->get('error_city');
        }

        $this->load->model('localisation/country');
        $country_info = $this->model_localisation_country->getCountry($request_data['country_id']);

        if ($country_info && $country_info['postcode_required'] && (utf8_strlen(trim($request_data['postcode'])) < 2 || utf8_strlen(trim($request_data['postcode'])) > 10)) {
            $this->error['postcode'] = $this->language->get('error_postcode');
        }

        if ($request_data['country_id'] == '') {
            $this->error['country'] = $this->language->get('error_country');
        }

        if (!isset($request_data['zone_id']) || $request_data['zone_id'] == '' || !is_numeric($request_data['zone_id'])) {
            $this->error['zone'] = $this->language->get('error_zone');
        }

        // Customer Group
        if (isset($request_data['customer_group_id']) && is_array($this->config->get('config_customer_group_display')) && in_array($request_data['customer_group_id'], $this->config->get('config_customer_group_display'))) {
            $customer_group_id = $request_data['customer_group_id'];
        } else {
            $customer_group_id = $this->config->get('config_customer_group_id');
        }

        // Custom field validation
        $this->load->model('account/custom_field');
        $custom_fields = $this->model_account_custom_field->getCustomFields($customer_group_id);
        foreach ($custom_fields as $custom_field) {            
            if(in_array($custom_field['location'], $location)){
                if ($custom_field['required'] && empty($request_data['custom_field'][$custom_field['location']][$custom_field['custom_field_id']])) {
                    $this->error['custom_field'][$custom_field['custom_field_id']] = sprintf($this->language->get('error_custom_field'), $custom_field['name']);
                } elseif (($custom_field['type'] == 'text') && !empty($custom_field['validation']) && !filter_var($request_data['custom_field'][$custom_field['location']][$custom_field['custom_field_id']], FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array('options' => array('regexp' => $custom_field['validation'])))) {
                    $this->error['custom_field'][$custom_field['custom_field_id']] = sprintf($this->language->get('error_custom_field'), $custom_field['name']);
                }
            }
        }

        if($password_check){
            if ((utf8_strlen($request_data['password']) < 4) || (utf8_strlen($request_data['password']) > 20)) {
                $this->error['password'] = $this->language->get('error_password');
            }

            if ($request_data['confirm'] != $request_data['password']) {
                $this->error['confirm'] = $this->language->get('error_confirm');
            }
        }

        if(!$this->error){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting values from edittext

```
String emailStr = email.getText().toString().trim();
String passwordStr = password.getText().toString().trim();
String firstnameStr = firstname.getText().toString().trim();
String lastnameStr = lastname.getText().toString().trim();
String telephoneStr = telephone.getText().toString().trim();
String confirmStr = confirm.getText().toString().trim();


 Call<DefaultResponse> call = RetrofitClient
                .getInstance()
                .getApi()
                .createUser(emailStr, passwordStr , firstnameStr, lastnameStr , telephoneStr , confirmStr );
```

And your way to check empty editttext is not works fine change it a responsive way

Comment: remove all edittext conditions for check and fill all fileds and check again

Comment: Debug or log    Request request = requestBuilder.build(); this line to chack what request you sending on server

Comment: getting this error

 Request{method=POST, url=https://www.glamorousshe.com/index.php?route=customapi/customer/register, tag=Request{method=POST, url=https://www.glamorousshe.com/index.php?route=customapi/customer/register, tag=null}}

Comment: What happen can you help me to slove this issue or what ?? 
pls let me know @SandeepParish

Comment: Your retrofit client did not attach your parameters with url

Comment: check and fix the bug

Comment: can you explain me

Comment: i din't try it in postman i debug it and check that your values is not post with url

Comment: its passes parameter in retrofit class because its help to call all products in gridview

Comment: with url it not work
you can try it with postman
by passing parameter in Body 
raw
{
pass all parameter here
}

Comment: Can you give me code for Basic Authentication in Retrofit @SandeepParish